# Process adjacent overlapping pairs from the java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am working on a problem that I need to process overlapping pairs from the stream.

for example, consider the list → ["lion","fox","hare","carrot"] .
So output will be

lion eats fox

fox eats hare

hare eats carrot.

Output items are always one less than that of the original list. I am currently using java 8 . here's my code

> Code

```java
static <T,R> Function <T, Stream<R>> pairMap(BiFunction<T,T,R> mapper) 
    {
        return new Function<> () {
            T previous = null;
            boolean hasPrevious;

            public Stream<R> apply(T t)
            {
                Stream<R> result;
                if(!hasPrevious)
                {
                    hasPrevious = true;
                    result = Stream.empty();
                }
                else
                {
                    result = Stream.of(mapper.apply(previous, t));
                }
                previous = t;
                return result;
            }
        };
    }
    static <T> Stream<T> getAdjecentOverlappingStream(List<T> list)
    {
        return list.stream().flatMap(pairMap((a,b) -> a+" eats "+ b));
    }
```

> Calling method

```java
//consider the class name I am working with is StreamUtils.  
StreamUtils.getAdjecentOverlappingStream(Arrays.asList("lion","fox","hare","carrot"))
.forEach(System.out::println);;
```

But this code giving me error as  **error: cannot infer type arguments for Function<T,R>**

See full error.

> Error

```java
StreamLecture.java:83: error: cannot infer type arguments for Function<T,R>
        return new Function<> () {
                           ^
  reason: cannot use '<>' with anonymous inner classes
  where T,R are type-variables:
    T extends Object declared in interface Function
    R extends Object declared in interface Function
StreamLecture.java:106: error: incompatible types: inference variable R#1 has incompatible bounds
        return list.stream().flatMap(pairMap((a,b) -> a+" eats "+ b));
                                    ^
    equality constraints: T#2
    lower bounds: String,R#2
  where R#1,T#1,T#2,R#2,T#3 are type-variables:
    R#1 extends Object declared in method <R#1>flatMap(Function<? super T#1,? extends Stream<? extends R#1>>)
    T#1 extends Object declared in interface Stream
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>getAdjecentOverlappingStream(List<T#2>)
    R#2 extends Object declared in method <T#3,R#2>pairMap(BiFunction<T#3,T#3,R#2>)
    T#3 extends Object declared in method <T#3,R#2>pairMap(BiFunction<T#3,T#3,R#2>)
Note: StreamLecture.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
```

Please help me fix this error.
thanks ✌

Comment: Just use `new Function<T, Stream<R>>` and in Java 11+ you don't need that

Comment: Also calling method gives me this error after the fix you have said error: incompatible types: inference variable R#1 has incompatible bounds
        return list.stream().flatMap(pairMap((a,b) -> a+" eats "+ b));

Comment: As you need in `Stream<T>` then cast it like `(Stream<T>)list.stream()...`

Comment: like this list.stream().flatMap((Stream<T> )pairMap((a,b) -> a+" eats "+ b)); ?

Comment: thanks that solved my problem.

Comment: Since `(a,b) -> a+" eats "+ b` evaluates to a `String`, you should declare the return type as `Stream<String>`. Do **not** cast to `Stream<T>`, for this one caller, `T` happens to be `String`, but the next caller might pass in a `List<Integer>` and the method should not pretend to return `Stream<Integer>` when it used string concatenation.

Comment: Add your answer with your suggestions @Eklavya

Comment: @Holger if you have different approach to solve this , please add your answer.